# Query jsonb array on RAIL 5.2 postgres12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

on rails 5 with PostgreSQL 12.2, I have this model

```
  create_table "training_opportunities", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "contact_id"
    t.string "situation"
    t.boolean "cpf"
    t.string "software_interest"
    t.string "training_type_interest"
    t.string "month"
    t.text "comment"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "status"
    t.boolean "pole_emploi", default: false
    t.jsonb "history", default: [], array: true
    t.boolean "to_be_call", default: false
    t.boolean "is_flag", default: false
    t.boolean "is_star", default: false
    t.index ["contact_id"], name: "index_training_opportunities_on_contact_id"
  end
```

I try to query TrainingOpportunity by the content of the history. For example, in rails c

`TrainingOpportunity.first.history`

give

```
[{"date"=>"2020-07-03 09:05:00 +0000", "step"=>"ID POLE EMPLOI : 1242050E - architecture intérieur - débutante qlq notions de 3D  - environ 2500€CPF - devis envoyé le 03/07"}, {"date"=>"20/07/03", "step"=>"reprise automatique de l'existant"}]
```

I try to find it whith this query:

```
TrainingOpportunity.where('history @> {"step":"ID POLE EMPLOI : 1242050E - architecture intérieur - débutante qlq notions de 3D  - environ 2500€CPF - devis envoyé le 03/07"}')
```

but I've got this error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{")
LINE 1: ...* FROM "training_opportunities" WHERE (history @> {"step":"I...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "training_opportunities".* FROM "training_opportunities" WHERE (history @> {"step":"ID POLE EMPLOI : 1242050E - architecture intérieur - débutante qlq notions de 3D  - environ 2500€CPF - devis envoyé le 03/07"}) LIMIT $1
```

I tried :

```
TrainingOpportunity.where('history @> ?', '[{"step":"ID POLE EMPLOI : 1242050E - architecture intérieur - débutante qlq notions de 3D  - environ 2500€CPF - devis envoyé le 03/07"}]')
```

but i got this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "[{"step":"ID POLE EMPLOI : 1242050E - architecture intérieur - débutante qlq notions de 3D  - environ 2500€CPF - devis envoyé le 03/07"}]")
LINE 1: ...* FROM "training_opportunities" WHERE (history @> '[{"step":...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
: SELECT  "training_opportunities".* FROM "training_opportunities" WHERE (history @> '[{"step":"ID POLE EMPLOI : 1242050E - architecture intérieur - débutante qlq notions de 3D  - environ 2500€CPF - devis envoyé le 03/07"}]') LIMIT $1
```

### after rmlockerd  proposition , I tried the following solution

but no ones works.

```
TrainingOpportunity.where('history @> ?', {"date"=>"20/07/03"}.to_json)
  TrainingOpportunity Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "training_opportunities".* FROM "training_opportunities" WHERE (history @> '{"date":"20/07/03"}') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "{"date":"20/07/03"}")
LINE 1: ...* FROM "training_opportunities" WHERE (history @> '{"date":"...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  Unexpected array element.
: SELECT  "training_opportunities".* FROM "training_opportunities" WHERE (history @> '{"date":"20/07/03"}') LIMIT $1



TrainingOpportunity.where('history @> ?', {'date'=>'20/07/03'}.to_json)
  TrainingOpportunity Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "training_opportunities".* FROM "training_opportunities" WHERE (history @> '{"date":"20/07/03"}') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "{"date":"20/07/03"}")
LINE 1: ...* FROM "training_opportunities" WHERE (history @> '{"date":"...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  Unexpected array element.
: SELECT  "training_opportunities".* FROM "training_opportunities" WHERE (history @> '{"date":"20/07/03"}') LIMIT $1



TrainingOpportunity.where('history @> ?', {date:'20/07/03'}.to_json)
  TrainingOpportunity Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "training_opportunities".* FROM "training_opportunities" WHERE (history @> '{"date":"20/07/03"}') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "{"date":"20/07/03"}")
LINE 1: ...* FROM "training_opportunities" WHERE (history @> '{"date":"...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  Unexpected array element.
: SELECT  "training_opportunities".* FROM "training_opportunities" WHERE (history @> '{"date":"20/07/03"}') LIMIT $1


TrainingOpportunity.where('history @> ?', [{date:'20/07/03'}].to_json)
  TrainingOpportunity Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "training_opportunities".* FROM "training_opportunities" WHERE (history @> '[{"date":"20/07/03"}]') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "[{"date":"20/07/03"}]")
LINE 1: ...* FROM "training_opportunities" WHERE (history @> '[{"date":...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
: SELECT  "training_opportunities".* FROM "training_opportunities" WHERE (history @> '[{"date":"20/07/03"}]') LIMIT $1
```

### I try to specify the first element of the array

```
TrainingOpportunity.where('history --> 0 = ?', '{"date"=>"20/07/03"}')
  TrainingOpportunity Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "training_opportunities".* FROM "training_opportunities" WHERE (history --> 0 = '{"date"=>"20/07/03"}') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at end of input)
LINE 1: ...ies" WHERE (history --> 0 = '{"date"=>"20/07/03"}') LIMIT $1
                                                                       ^
: SELECT  "training_opportunities".* FROM "training_opportunities" WHERE (history --> 0 = '{"date"=>"20/07/03"}') LIMIT $1
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

My original answer (and your initial attempts) assumed a column declared with the Postgres `jsonb` datatype. However, you have
*also* created it as a Postgres `Array` (i.e., `jsonb[]` rather than `jsonb`). Postgres supports the `@>` operator for both arrays and jsonb types, and there's some sort of interaction between the two that I'm frankly not equipped to help you untangle. The good news is for what you seem to be wanting I don't think it's necessary. You have a couple of options:

1. If you will be doing lots of querying of this data, consider normalising it into a `History` model and just use a `has_many` relationship on `Training Opportunity`. In addition to making querying easier, you get all the other goodness of a model like validations, etc.
2. If you really want to keep this as JSON, I suggest to recreate the `history` column as just a `jsonb` type (without the `array: true`). You can still treat it as an array in practice (since arrays are valid JSON), and the `@>` operator will work as I outline below.

```rb
TrainingOpportunity.where('history @> ?', [{step:"reprise automatique de l'existant"}].to_json)
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<TrainingOpportunity id: 153, history: [..., {"date"=>"20/07/03", "step"=>"reprise automatique de l'existant"}], ...>

TrainingOpportunity.where('history @> ?', [{date: "20/07/03"}].to_json)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<TrainingOpportunity id: 153, history: [..., {"date"=>"20/07/03", "step"=>"reprise automatique de l'existant"}], ...>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it doesn't work, I don't know why ? I have edit my initial post

Comment: I loaded your sample data into a model in my environment and those queries worked for me. I'll have a look.

Comment: thanks mlockerd, i'm on mac os or heroku , on postgres 12.2 , rails 5.2

Comment: may be this operator could help ? #>>

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The JSON operators like ``#>>`` work on ``jsonb`` columns, but yours is set up as a ``jsonb[]`` column, which means Postgres treats it primarily as an array, so only the [Array operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html) work on it. If what you want is to use the JSON operators to query your data directly, my answer stands; migrate the column to eliminate the array part. It's adding complexity but no value to you.